# Is there a way to get a class reference from its type?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

So I'm working on a game engine, and I'm trying to call these functions used in classes that inherit a parent "behavior" class. I'm trying to implement this by taking all of the child classes using `System.Reflection` and calling the function using that child class reference. However, the way I'm doing it requires me to work with Types, and in order to call these functions I need a reference to the class. I'm trying to call a virtual void that has been overridden in the child class, so an instance of the class is probably required.

```
// Initializing variable "b" which is what stores all of the child classes
public static Type[] b = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseBehavior)).GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseBehavior))).ToArray();

// Executing Start Function
    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        MethodInfo s = b[i].GetMethod("Start", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.IgnoreReturn, null, CallingConventions.HasThis, new Type[] { }, null);
        if (s != null) Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
        if (s != null && b[i] != null)
        {
            s.Invoke(b[i], null); // Requires an object reference, not a type
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Method");
        }
    }
```

Is there something I should change about what I'm doing, or is there a function that I'm missing. I haven't been able to find answers anywhere else so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the classes in question? If this is e.g. one-time configuration, it might be viable to create instances on the fly, if you need to access existing instances, a different solution is required. It might also be viable to use attributes and static methods instead of base class + override in the first case.

Comment: Well *which* instance do you want to call the method on? You could potentially create a new one, if its has a constructor with no parameters - but is that definitely what you want? Perhaps it would be better to create a dictionary of instances in some well-specified place, and then you don't need to use reflection at all? (You could always use a unit test to validate that your dictionary does indeed contain an instance of every non-abstract class derived from BaseBehavior.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have to instantiate an instance of the object then change the method to `static`. Currently you are explicitly passing `BindingFlags.Instance` which means calling the method will require an object reference. If it is static you can then pass `null` as the first argument of the `Invoke()` method as you do not require an object reference for such methods. Try:

```
    MethodInfo s = b[i].GetMethod("Start", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.IgnoreReturn, null, CallingConventions.HasThis, new Type[] { }, null);
    if (s != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
        s.Invoke(null, null); // Pass null as the first parameter
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Method");
    }
```

If you need to call an instance method then you'll need to create an instance of the `b[i]` type before passing it to `Invoke()`:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(b[i]);
s.Invoke(instance, null);
```

This assumes a parameterless constructor on the type. If there is no such constructor available then you'll need to pass the requisite parameters into `Activator.CreateInstance`. But then you'll need to know more about the type than this generic solution would suggest...

Comment: The problem is I want to call a virtual void that is overridden in the child class, so I probably will need to create an instance. Sorry I didn't specify that I'll fix the post.

Comment: @398utubzyt I've amended the answer, although I would take note of the comments by others on your question - there are probably better ways of doing this...

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot `Activator.CreateInstance()` existed. But I was able to ride off of that function and I got it to work! Thank you again, I've been trying to figure this out for days.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another approach. Just create a delegate that points to a start method and make it visible from the outside. Then you can just go ahead and call start method using that delegate. It should be way faster then using the reflection.